# Laravel: How to create link buttons on a view dynamically?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I'm making a College Administration website where a professor can log in.

I have a dashboard, where my dynamically generated button should be placed: (right now it just has dummy buttons!)

[image: dashboard]
Generated by this view file, which I will have to modify soon:

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
<h1>IA DASHBOARD</h1>
<br>
    <div class="grid2">
            <a href="{{ url('/subcode/{subcode}') }}" ><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-outline-primary btn-custom">SUBCODE 1</button></a>
            <a href="{{ url('/subcode/{subcode}') }}" ><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-outline-primary btn-custom">SUBCODE 2</button></a>
            <a href="{{ url('/subcode/{subcode}') }}" ><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-outline-primary btn-custom">SUBCODE 3</button></a>
        </div>
```

---

### Tables in the Database:

- the table `iamarks` contains the data (student info, and marks) that is to be displayed after `/subcode/{subcode}` narrows it down to records of just the students that are in the class assigned to current logged-in professor.
- `classroom_mappers` is a table used to map a professor to a classroom with a subject. It makes sure that one classroom only has one professor for a particular subject.

---

the routes currently in my ***web.php***:

```
route::get('/ia', 'IAController@show')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/subcode/{subcode}', 'IAController@showTable')->middleware('auth');
```

...and these are the methods inside my controller:

```
//shows buttons to the user:
public function show(){
    $subcodes = DB::table('classroom_mappers')
                    ->select('subcode')
                    ->where([['PID','=', auth()->user()->PID]])
                    ->get();
    return view('ia',compact('subcodes'));
}

//when user clicks a button, subcode is to be generated and a table is to be shown:
//it works, I tried it by manually typing in subcode value in URL.

public function showTable($subcode){
    $sem = DB::table('classroom_mappers')
               ->where([['PID','=', auth()->user()->PID],
                        ['subcode','=',$subcode]])
               ->pluck('semester');
    $division = DB::table('classroom_mappers')
                    ->where([['PID','=', auth()->user()->PID],
                             ['semester','=',$sem],
                             ['subcode','=',$subcode]])
                    ->pluck('division');
    $data = DB::table('iamarks')
                ->where([['semester','=',$sem],
                         ['division','=',$division],
                         ['subcode','=',$subcode]])
                ->get();

    return view('subcode',compact('data'));
}
```

---

### My Problem:

To be able to generate the `{subcode}` in the URL dynamically, I want to create buttons in the dashboard using the data `$subcodes`. The controller hands over the `$subcodes` (an array of subject codes which belong to logged in professor) which are to be made into buttons from the `show()` method.

The buttons should have the name `{subcode}` and when clicked, should append the same subject code in the URL as `{subcode}`.

1. How do I make use of `$subcodes` and make the buttons dynamically?
2. How do I make sure the buttons made for one user are not visible to another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution, thanks to Air Petr.

Apparently, you can't nest blade syntax like `{{some_stuff {{ more_stuff }} }}` and it generates a wrong php code. I modified the solution by Air Petr to:

```
<div class="grid2">
    @foreach ($subcodes as $subcode)
        <a href="<?php echo e(url('/subcode/'.$subcode->subcode));?>">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-outline-primary btn-custom">
                <?php
                    echo e($subcode->subcode);
                ?>
            </button>
        </a>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

It generates the buttons perfectly. The buttons for one user are not visible to another, since I'm using PID constraint in a query (['PID','=', auth()->user()->PID]).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can loop your codes to create buttons. Something like this (it's for "blade" template engine):

```
<div class="grid2">
    @foreach ($subcodes as $subcode)
        <a href="{{ url('/subcode/'.$subcode->subcode) }}" ><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-outline-primary btn-custom">{{ $subcode->subcode }}</button></a>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

2. Since you're using PID constrain in a query (`['PID','=', auth()->user()->PID]`), you'll get buttons for that specific PID. So there's no problem.

Comment: Could you check your syntax? I'm getting a syntax error when running that foreach loop. (I'm guessing it is due to a copy-paste error at the button name!)

Comment: This is the error:

" syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')' (View: resources\views\ia.blade.php) "

Comment: I got it. It was an error with laravel blade's auto php generation.  Nested {{  {{ }}  }} don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the passcodes array to view:

```
$subcodes = []; // Array retrieved from DB
return view('subcode', compact('subcodes'));
```

And in `subcode.blade.php`, loop through each subcode:

```
<div class="grid2">
  @foreach($subcodes as $subcode)
  <a href="{{ url('/subcode/' . $subcode->subcode) }}">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-outline-primary btn-custom">SUBCODE {{ $subcode->subcode }}</button>
  </a>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that works.  Is there a way I can restrict a user 'A' from accessing the URL that was only supposed to be visible to another user 'B' and vice versa? Right now, when user 'A' logs in, he can just type in the URL generated in B's button and see B's data.

Comment: You should be looking into Laravel Authorization (Gates and policies). https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization